# Another alien message, but from where?

Tags: cipher, outer-space

"Alright everyone. After your great success [decoding the stone tablet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48215/the-alien-message-what-does-it-mean), we need your help with another message. We picked up a long sequence of radio activity and we're sure it's a message from aliens."

"However, we don't know who sent the message. That's where you come in. Your mission is this: decode the message and **figure out where in the great wide universe this message came from**. Good luck."

```
-------------------------------------................................
......--.--.--.--.--.--.--.--.--.--.--.--.....-...-.--....-...-.--...
.-...-.--..............-..-..-..-...-..-..-..-.......................
....................-..-..-..-..-..-..-..-..-..-..-.........-..-..-..
-..-..-..-..-..-..-............-..-..-..-..-..-..-..-..-.............
..-..-..-..-..-..-..-..-..................-..-..-..-..-..-..-........
.............-..-..-..-..-..-........................-..-..-..-..-...
........................-..-..-..-..............................-..-.
.-.................................-..-..............................
......-......................................------------------------
-------------..................-.....................--.-.--.-.--...-
...--.-.--.-.--......-..-..-...--...-...-..-......-..........-....-..
....-...-....-..-........................-...........................
.........-.....................--.-.--.-.--...-...--.-.--.-.--.......
-.-.......-...-...--.-.--...........-..-.-..-..-...-....-....-.-.....
...................-..................-------------------------------
------..................-.....................--...--.-.--...-...--..
.--.-.--.......-.-.--....-...-......-..-....-.........-....-.-....-..
.-.......-........................-..................................
..-.....................--...--.-.--...-...--...--.-.--.........-.--.
.......-....-.-..-...--......-..-....-.--...-...-.......-............
............-..................-------------------------------------.
................-......................--.-.--.-.--..-...........----
---....--....-...-...-.--...--.-.--...--............-..-..-.-..-..-..
.-..-..-..................-.........-..........................-.....
.................--.-.--.-.--..-...........-------.....-...--.......-
.--...--.-.--...--............-..-..-.--.-.-....-....--..............
....-.......-.-.........------------------...........................
.........-......-------.......................-.--...--...--.-.--....
-----------...-....-.-..-..-....-....-.........-...-.-..-.........-..
.....-.........-...-......................-.........-...-............
..........-.--.-.--.-...--------------------...-..-....-.-...........
...............-..-......-..........................-.........-......
....................-.........-..........................-.........-.
.........................-----------.................................
...............................-.......-............................-
.--....-............................-.-.....-........................
....-.......-....................................-...................
.......-----.....-..........................-...-.....-..............
............-...-.....-..........................-...-.....-......---
----.............-----.....-.--.-.--...--.......................-..-.
-.-..-.--................-----..-....-......-.................-...-..
-.............................-...-..-.............................-.
..-..-.............................-----..-..........................
............................................------...................
............-....-...............................-.--.-..............
.................-.-..-...............................-....-.........
......................------.........................................
...............................-----................................-
...-................................-...-............................
....-...-................................-----.......................
.................................-------------------------------------
```

---

Hint:

> You don't need a telescope to see the star it came from.

Comment: Would it be possible to break up the message for legibility? Rather than need to scroll forever just to see the whole thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Rejecting my previous answer as incorrect, the parameters determined by **2012rcampion** are a close match for the Solar system (as in OUR solar system).
>
>  With the semi-major axis of Mercury (the first planet) of $70\times10^6$ km and that of the Earth (the third planet) of $150\times10^6$ km, the ratio is $2\frac{1}{7}$ precisely.
>
>  The radius of the Earth is $0.009145$ solar radii, which is practically $10^{-2}$ as expected.
>
>  Hence, the origin of the signal must be **the Earth**.

Answer (score 10):

This is only the first step.

> The message has 3589 symbols, either dots or dashes. These symbols can be arranged in a 37×97 grid, which looks promising:
>
> ```
> #####################################
> .....................................
> .##.##.##.##.##.##.##.##.##.##.##.##.
> ....#...#.##....#...#.##....#...#.##.
> .............#..#..#..#...#..#..#..#.
> .....................................
> .....#..#..#..#..#..#..#..#..#..#..#.
> ........#..#..#..#..#..#..#..#..#..#.
> ...........#..#..#..#..#..#..#..#..#.
> ..............#..#..#..#..#..#..#..#.
> .................#..#..#..#..#..#..#.
> ....................#..#..#..#..#..#.
> .......................#..#..#..#..#.
> ..........................#..#..#..#.
> .............................#..#..#.
> ................................#..#.
> ...................................#.
> .....................................
> #####################################
> ..................#..................
> ...##.#.##.#.##...#...##.#.##.#.##...
> ...#..#..#...##...#...#..#......#....
> ......#....#......#...#....#..#......
> ..................#..................
> ..................#..................
> ...##.#.##.#.##...#...##.#.##.#.##...
> ....#.#.......#...#...##.#.##........
> ...#..#.#..#..#...#....#.#..#.#......
> ..................#..................
> #####################################
> ..................#..................
> ...##...##.#.##...#...##...##.#.##...
> ....#.#.##....#...#......#..#....#...
> ......#....#.#....#...#.......#......
> ..................#..................
> ..................#..................
> ...##...##.#.##...#...##...##.#.##...
> ......#.##........#....#.#..#...##...
> ...#..#....#.##...#...#.......#......
> ..................#..................
> #####################################
> .................#...................
> ...##.#.##.#.##..#...........#######.
> ...##....#...#...#.##...##.#.##...##.
> ...........#..#..#.#..#..#...#..#..#.
> .................#.........#.........
> .................#...................
> ...##.#.##.#.##..#...........#######.
> ....#...##.......#.##...##.#.##...##.
> ...........#..#..#.#..#.##...#....##.
> .................#..#......#.........
> ##################...................
> .................#......#######......
> .................#.##...##...##.#.##.
> ...###########...#....#.#..#..#....#.
> ...#.........#...#.#..#.........#....
> ...#.........#...#...................
> ...#.........#...#...................
> ...#.##.#.##.#...####################
> ...#..#....#.#.......................
> ...#..#......#.......................
> ...#.........#.......................
> ...#.........#.......................
> ...#.........#.......................
> ...###########.......................
> .....................................
> ....#.......#........................
> ....#.##....#........................
> ....#.#.....#........................
> ....#.......#........................
> ............#........................
> ..#####.....#........................
> ..#...#.....#........................
> ..#...#.....#........................
> ..#...#.....#......#######...........
> ..#####.....#.##.#.##...##...........
> ............#..#.#.#..#.##...........
> .....#####..#....#......#............
> .....#...#..#........................
> .....#...#..#........................
> .....#...#..#........................
> .....#####..#........................
> .....................................
> .........######......................
> .........#....#......................
> .........#.##.#......................
> .........#.#..#......................
> .........#....#......................
> .........######......................
> .....................................
> .............#####...................
> .............#...#...................
> .............#...#...................
> .............#...#...................
> .............#####...................
> .....................................
> #####################################
> ```
>
> I've replaced the dashes with hash marks for clarity. (The message could also be represented a black-and-white pixel map.)

The top row ...

> ... looks like the definition of numbers and the sketches below make use of these numbers. The numbers are a bit pattern in a 2×3 block: The top two bits are always set to mark the glyph as a number. The middle row are the 1 and 2 bits, the bottom row are the 4 and 8 rows.
>
>  Although only the numbers from 0 to 11 are given, we can theoretically construct numbers from 0 to 15:
>
> ```
>  0 ##   1 ##   2 ##   3 ##   4 ##   5 ##   6 ##   7 ## 
>           #       #     ##            #       #     ## 
>                                #      #      #      #
>
>
>  8 ##   9 ##  10 ##  11 ##  12 ##  13 ##  14 ##  15 ## 
>           #       #     ##            #       #     ## 
>     #      #      #      #     ##     ##     ##     ##
> ```

The next block ...

> ... shows simple arithmetics. The three 1×3 glyphs are operators:
>
> ```
>  + #    - #    * #    /      ^ #    = #
>    #      #      #      #
>    #                                  #
> ```
>
> yielding the equations:
>
> ```
>     1 + 2 = 3        5 - 4 = 1
>     6 + 4 = 10      11 + 11 = 0
>
>     2 * 3 = 6        4 / 2 = 2
>     4 * 3 = 12       6 / 2 = 3
>
>       3^2 = 9
>       2^3 = 8
> ```
>
> The last sum `11 + 11 = 0` might suggest that either overflow isn't handled or that that the arithmetic is modular. (But modulo 22 would require more digit glyphs.)

The stuff to the right ...

> ... of the power equations probably has something to do with representation of rational numbers. The big 10×10 square is labelled `10 ^ 2`.

Comment: That was too quick guess. +1 I was thinking of it as Morse code -> Bacon Cipher(Binary) -> Text

Comment: It looks like braille ... but I'm having issues with some of the letters.

Comment: The first set of symbols appears to be the numbers 0 to 11 in this alien braille.

Answer (score 7):

The message as an image, based on [M Oehm's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49100/9718):

> [image]

My interpretation:

> [image]

---

> * The top section counts up in binary numbers from 0 to 11.  It's similar to the numbering system in the [Arecibo message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message).
>  * The next six sections describe some mathematical operators.  In order, they are addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation, and fractions.  There's a typo in the subtraction section, which has an equation that reads $11+11=0$ instead of $11-11=0$.
>  * The bottom section describes a solar system with four planets.  The sun is 100 times more massive than the third planet (so the planet is likely a gas giant), and the ratio between the orbital radii of the first and third planets is $2\tfrac{1}{7}$.

Comment: I can confirm that 11+11=0 is a typo. I'll fix it when I get home. Also, 100 is not mass.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that **2012rcampion** correctly determined that $2\frac{1}{7}$ is the ratio of semi-major axes, I will propose my best guess of the system of origin for the signal:

> **Kepler-286** at [R.A. 19h22m42s and Dec. +48°17'39''](http://www.openexoplanetcatalogue.com/planet/Kepler-286%20b/).

The system has 4 planets with the semi-major axes ratio of the third to the first one of $2.21$ (using Kepler's third law $\left (\frac{T_3}{T_1}\right )^2 = \left (\frac{R_3}{R_1}\right )^3$), which is reasonably close to $2\frac{1}{7}$. The ratio of the radius of the star to the radius of the planet is $10^{1.85 \pm 0.16}$, which is again consistent with the message.

This is the closest match I could find in the [Exoplanet Archive](http://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/index.html).

My next best guesses would be **Kepler-24** and **Kepler-215**.

Comment: A good answer, but not the correct one.

Comment: I just realized it: the parameters match our Solar system even closer. In fact, they're almost spot on.

Comment: You're on to something.

Answer (score 0):

This is a canonical answer to explain everything in the message. This explains the fixed version. The fixed errors are as follows:

> Replaced 11+11=0 with 11-11=0.
>  Replaced 9/3=[1/3] with 3/9=[1/3].

Step 1: Finding the image.

> There are 3589 characters in the message. 3589 is a semi-prime number (37x97). This means if you try to arrange them in a grid, there are only two ways to do it evenly. As it happens, the message starts with 37 dashes in a row.
>
>  By arranging the message like that, you can see a pattern emerge. This pattern can also be shown as a black and white image (dashes are black pixels, dots white pixels), as follows (scaled up 500%):
>
>  [image]

Step 2: Decoding the message.

> At the very top of the message is a sequence of 12 2x3 symbols. These symbols are the numbers 0 through 11, as shown by the bars below them.
>  Each number symbol has the top two blocks filled in. From there the remaining blocks count the value of the symbol in binary starting at the top left, as follows:
>
> ```
>  ##
>  12
>  48
> ```
>
> Below the numbers are some equations, using the following 1x3 symbols:
>
> ```
>  +  -  *  /  ^  =
>  #  #        #  #
>  #  #  #  #
>  #     #        #
> ```
>
> The actual equations are as follows:
>
> ```
>  1+2=3   5-4=1
>  6+4=10  11-11=0
>  
>  2*3=6   4/2=2
>  4*3=12  6/2=3
>  
>  3^2=9
>  2^3=8
> ```
>
> To the right of the exponents are fractions. A fraction is shown as a large bar over a division problem. I will put brackets around them in this explanation. The problems are as follows:
>
> ```
>  1/2=[1/2]
>  3/9=[1/3]
>  4*[1/2]=2
> ```

Step 3: The diagram and the final reveal.

> Below all of the math is a diagram of a star system. Four planets are shown in the system, as is the star.
>
>  The star is marked 10^2, or 100; the third planet is marked 1.
>
>  Some distances are labeled as well. The distance from the star to the closest planet is marked 1, while the distance to the third planet is marked 2+[1/7].
>
>  At this point, looking at the numbers reveals that the depicted star system is the Solar System (as in where Earth is).
>
>  The ratio of the Sun's radius to the Earth's radius is ~100.
>  The ratio of Mercury's orbit to the Earth's orbit is ~2+[1/7].
>
>  As Earth is in both equations and is known to contain life, it is apparent that the message came from **Earth**.